# Why am I exceeding my VRAM limit in my games and not suffering from dramatic frame rate drops?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, performance, amd-radeon, gaming

Just like my other question, this isn't by any means a problem I'm complaining about, this is just something I want to know the secret behind.

> #### System Specifications
>
> - **CPU**: AMD A10-6790K 4.0 GHz
> - **GPU**: Sapphire Radeon R7 265 Dual-X 2 GB
> - **RAM**: 2 x Team 4 GB 1600 DDR3 = 8 GB
> - **OS**: Windows 8.1 Pro x64

As is written in the adapter information found in the screen resolution window, I seem to have

> - **Total Available Graphics Memory**: 5888 MB
> - **Dedicated Video Memory**: 2048 MB
> - **System Video Memory**: 0 MB
> - **Shared System Memory**: 3840 MB

I tested this in Middle-Earth: Shadow of Mordor, where the texture quality if set on high, it would require me to have at least 3GBs of VRAM.
and if set on ultra, it would require me to have at least 6GBs of VRAM.
I, of course, tried to set it on ultra and I suffered from the expected **DRAMATIC** frame rate drops so I set it on high and it's running perfectly.
So, am I not exceeding the limit of my fast VRAM? Isn't the shared system memory supposed to be slow, so if by any means the game tries to use it instead of my dedicated video memory because it's starting to run out of free space, won't it reduce performance because the shared video memory is slower than the dedicated?
That's it, thanks for spending your precious time reading my question :D

Comment: What are you using to measure the amount of VRAM your using?

Comment: I'm using the adapter information that are shown in the advanced settings in the screen resolution window and also DxDiag.

Comment: I can already tell you that its physically not possible for you to use more VRAM then you actually have.  So either the program isn't using 6GB of VRAM or its using 2GB VRAM and the rest is system memory.

Comment: I know so, that's why I'm saying how is the frame rate not dropping although it's obviously switching over to the shared system memory.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  The program your running isn't using your `Sapphire Radeon R7 265 ` but instead the `Radeon HD 8670D` based on the fact its reporting larger memory usage then 2GB to begin with.  Your [8670D](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor/12308/?p=r) is well within the specifications for the game.

Comment: Actually, Shadow of Mordor is using my R7 because it's saying
AMD R7 200 Series in the graphics card section in the settings.

Comment: Well the R7 is not capable of even using your system files, so its either switching, reporting the incorrect device, or using both devices.

Comment: Could it be that the 3 GBs warning given is based on a 1080p set. I'm running it on 1440x900 because of course a lower resolution means less VRAM usage.

Comment: Have you run the benchmark at a standard resolution?  I have no problem running this game on a 2GB Nvidia card at HD resolutions on High.

Comment: I have everything on ultra except texture quality on high and I'm running it at 40 (Min) - 45 (Avg) - 55-60 (Max)
When I set texture quality to ultra, it gets really laggy and reaches 2 FPS then jumps back to 40 and after seconds it gets to 2 again.
BTW, My native resolution is 1440x900.